# liferay search container pagination issue

Tags: liferay

**This is my Liferay search container code:**

```
MVC:BigInteger leaveTotalCount;
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay = (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        PortletURL iteratorURL = PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(request, themeDisplay.getPortletDisplay().getId(),
                themeDisplay.getPlid(), PortletRequest.RENDER_PHASE);
        SearchContainer<LeaveDetailsWrapper> searchContainer = null;
        searchContainer = new SearchContainer<>(request, null, null, SearchContainer.DEFAULT_CUR_PARAM,
                SearchContainer.DEFAULT_DELTA, iteratorURL, null, LmsLeaveDashboardConstant.BLANK_STRING);
        List<LeaveDetailsWrapper> leaveDetails;
        try {
            searchContainer.setDeltaConfigurable(true);
            leaveDetails = leaveLocalService.getLeaveDetails(null, null, null, null,
                    LmsLeaveDashboardUtils.getEmpCode(request), searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd());
            log.info(leaveDetails);
            leaveTotalCount = leaveLocalService.getLeaveDetailsCount(null, null, null, null,
                    LmsLeaveDashboardUtils.getEmpCode(request), -1, -1);
            searchContainer.setEmptyResultsMessage("No Data Found..!");
            searchContainer.setTotal(leaveTotalCount.intValue());
            searchContainer.setIteratorURL(iteratorURL);

            searchContainer.setResults(leaveDetails);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("ERROR:IntrahrmsLmsLeaveDashboardWebPortlet leaveSearchContianer" + e);
        }
        return searchContainer;

jsp:

    <liferay-ui:search-container searchContainer="${leaveInfoContainer}" iteratorURL="${iteratorURL}">
            <liferay-ui:search-container-results
                results="${leaveInfoContainer.getResults()}" />

            <liferay-ui:search-container-row
                className="com.intrahrms.lms.service.leavecustom.model.LeaveDetailsWrapper"
                modelVar="LeaveDetails">

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                    value="${LeaveDetails.leaveTypeName} Leave " name="Leave Type" />
                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="From Date">
                    <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                        value="${LeaveDetails.fromDate}" type="date" />
                </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="To Date">
                    <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" value="${LeaveDetails.toDate}"
                        type="date" />
                </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                    value="${LeaveDetails.totalDays}" name="Total Leave Days" />

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Applied Date">
                    <fmt:formatDate pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"
                        value="${LeaveDetails.appliedDate}" type="date" />
                </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>


                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                    value="${LeaveDetails.leaveStatus} " name="Status" />

                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
                    value="${LeaveDetails.projectManagerId}" name="Reporting Manager" />


                <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp path="/action.jsp"
                    align="center" />

            </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

            <liferay-ui:search-iterator markupView="lexicon" />
        </liferay-ui:search-container>
```

The problem is when I'm changing a pagination or change delta, it gives me whole record instead of filter record.

Answer (score 0):

Your search container seems to be doing the right thing as:

```
leaveDetails = leaveLocalService.getLeaveDetails(null, null, null, null,
                    LmsLeaveDashboardUtils.getEmpCode(request), searchContainer.getStart(), searchContainer.getEnd());
```

Think about this: you have just created the instance, what would you expect to be in start and end?

When you created your containers you told it about the parameters it shoudl use, but they are not being set on your JSP, for instance:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container emptyResultsMessage="there-are-no-file-entries" iteratorURL="${filesRenderUrl}" delta="${files_searchDelta}" total="${files_searchTotal}" curParam="files" deltaParam="files">
```

bottom line, if you want to control your search container in java methods like that, you will need to act accordingly to set your results:

```
private static int getStart( int current, int delta ) {

    return ( current - 1 ) * delta;
}

private static int getEnd( int first, int delta ) {

    return first + delta;
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept the answer if you see fit.